# I can't get my div based menu to appear

Tags: html, css, menu

I have created a menu using `ul` and `il` tags inside of a `div` tag.

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

..with the following style applied to the menu:

```
.menu
{
    background-position: center;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    background: #CBC396 url(metaltop-gray.gif) repeat-x top;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid #7E7567;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-top-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom-color: black;
}
.menu ul {
   clear:left;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
   text-align:center;
}
.menu ul li {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   right:50%;
}
.menu ul li a {
   display:block;
   margin:0 0 0 1px;
   padding:3px 10px;
   background: #CBC396 url(metaltop-gray.gif) top repeat-x;
   color:#000;
   text-decoration:none;
   line-height:1.3em;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
   background:#369;
   color:#fff;
}
.menu ul li a.active,
.menu ul li a.active:hover {
   color:#fff;
   background:#000;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

When I run page in Google Chrome and resize page,  the menu disappears.  Also, this menu never show up in IE.  What could be wrong?
===================edit========================
please see  images
when page is full screen menu is ok
[image]

---

but when i resize page page become lik this
[image]
as you see in image,menu become hide and don't scroll

**and as i mention,in IE menu never show!!!**

Comment: I've seen this in IE9 and no issues in chrome
http://jsfiddle.net/dF2MD/

Comment: I *would* suggest a `overflow: hidden;` in your `#menu` block to prevent the scrollbar from appearing when the browser window is too narrow.

Comment: width: 100%; will throw it in IE, background needs to ne more specific: use 
     background-attachment: relative; 
     background-image: url('/images/newface/header2.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
     background-position: right top;
     background-color: #dee1e6;

Comment: @AdamSweeney:but it have issues for me!ayman:but my problem is not scroll bar .my problem is that menu hide!

Comment: The part you pasted here seems ok. To me it seems most likely that it's caused by something else, maybe faulty javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it may work fine, just change your `.menu`:

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: #CBC396 url(metaltop-gray.gif) repeat-x top;
}
```

try this it should work fine in all browser.

```
<div class="menuwrapper">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
.menuwrapper {
 background: #CBC396 url(metaltop-gray.gif) repeat-x top;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
 border-top: 1px solid #7E7567;
 border-top-color: #CCCCCC;
 border-bottom-color: black;
 border-bottom: 4px solid black;

 }

.menu
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: #CBC396 url(metaltop-gray.gif) repeat-x top;
    width: 340px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.menu ul {
   float:left;
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   text-align:center;
}
.menu ul li {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
.menu ul li a {
   display:block;
   margin:0 0 0 1px;
   padding:3px 10px;
   background: #CBC396 url(metaltop-gray.gif) top repeat-x;
   color:#000;
   text-decoration:none;
   line-height:1.3em;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
   background:#369;
   color:#fff;
}
.menu ul li a.active,
.menu ul li a.active:hover {
   color:#fff;
   background:#000;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: no!new code do not work.it appear like image in my question...i run your new code in IE,AND IE dont show me any menu

Comment: i dont know why you are getting this error i am getting to display your code and mine code in all browser. may be it is due to some other elements in page, at this point you'll have to figure out the way, these code as such are working fine.

Comment: ok..it seem to you trust.i copy/past your code i simple html and it work finetnx

Answer (score 0):

It is the normal on my machine. May be because you did not post all code. It can help if you remove all "position:relative" and all positioning properties.

I think you want to align menu in the middle Use this command to be better.

```
.menu ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  width: 350px;
 }
.menu ul li {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
```

Your code display this on my machine and same on chrome in any size. I would like to help, but i don't know what your problem.

[image]